# How can concatenate two strings (regex) in Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am working on a Jmeter login script.
When I log in, I need to make a POST with certain parameters:
[image]
This is how I do it in Jmeter:
[image]

The problem is that whenever I create the gxstate like in the next picture:
[image]

the value I  get is something like this:

> `{"OLVIDO_Visible":"0","_EventName":"","_EventGridId":"","_EventRowId":"","FORM_Class":"form-horizontal FormLoginPage","vIDIOMA_Values":"{\"isset\":true,\"s\":\"S\",\"v\":[[\"S\",\"EspaÃ±ol\"],[\"E\",\"English\"],[\"P\",\"PortuguÃ©s\"]]}","vAPPLICATIONCLIENTID":"","GX_FocusControl":"vUSERNAME","GX_AJAX_KEY":"###############################","AJAX_SECURITY_TOKEN":"##################################################################","GX_CMP_OBJS":{},"sCallerURL":"","GX_WEBSOCKET_ID":"3b3c20c2-ffb7-4fe1-8e05-9e32398560df","GX_CLI_NAV":"true","GX_THEME":"WorkWithPlusTheme","GX_RES_PROVIDER":"com.genexus.webpanels.GXResourceProvider"}`

which is different from the one in the picture because its missing this at the end:

```
"_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0"
```

I tried everything to concatenate them but my solutions are not working. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this site to improve regex if that's the problem in your case, it helped me a lot:
https://regex101.com/
Maybe the regex should be : GXState:{"(.+)"} instead of value='(.*?)'

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Maybe I did not explained myself correctly. What I have in the response body and what I get using value='(.*?)' is "correct''. To get to this regex I used https://regexr.com/ ...The problem is that when the petition happens, it adds more stuff to the GxState

Comment: So, you want to add this string: "_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0" to the ${GXState} ? If this is what you need than simply put in the VALOR :  ${GXState}"_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0"  and JMeter will automatically concatenate them.

Comment: Yes, look at the first picture I added to this post. Thats what I want to achieve. I am having an http 403 error and I am pretty sure that one of the problems I am having is what I send in the parameters

Comment: I really appreciate your help but doing what you suggested me does something like this: {.....................},"_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0" and what I want is like this {........,"_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0"} Just like in the picture

Comment: Use this regex: value='{(.*?)}' to exclude the bracket from the match and then in the Valor column use this value **{${GXState},"_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0"}**

Comment: This is the answer I get for doing that {${GXState},"_MODE":"","Mode":"","IsModified":"1","IsConfirmed":"0"}