# Why do I still keep having error 403 response code in JMETER?

Tags: jmeter

I am working on a Jmeter login script made with Blazemeter and whenever I try to do a post I get a 403 response code. I already made several questions on regards to this problem and I did all the things users suggested me, but I keep having the same error.

So my script starts with a get that I create like this:
[image]

Whenever I run my script, in a second user, the header of the petition is sent correctly with all the necessary information. For the first user, cookies do not appear in petition. Its Like this:
[image]

Then I do a post. The ajax token is obtained correctly:
[image]

This is the extra things I have:

1. Authorization Manager with url, username, password, domain and
   mechanism
2. Cookie manager
3. Header manager with cookies like this: ${COOKIE_GX_CLIENT_ID}
4. DNS Cache manager
5. HTTP Cache manager
6. HTTP request defaults

I have done everything to solve this 403 problem but nothing is working. The only thing that I think could be generating me a problem is the parameters I send to the post. Apart from admin and password, I also have to send a gx state which is something with the next form:

GxState: {....}

I already asked about the problem I have with gxstate in the next post and someone tried to help me but I still cant solve it and if I solve it, I dont know if that is going to solve my 403 problem:
[How can concatenate two strings (regex) in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802318/how-can-concatenate-two-strings-regex-in-jmeter)

Any suggestions? I am new to Jmeter and I am desperate to solve this problem

Comment: Regarding use JMeter to test Genexus Applications, I think you can find this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/66856859/4825845

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like you might have some trouble with a proxy interfering in your test. JMeter will not use any system-wide proxy settings.

If this is a possible explanation in your environment, try using the advanced tab of the HTTP Request Sampler or use HTTP Request Defaults at Test Plan level.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the response. I did what you told me too and It still does not work. I added the proxy name, the port, the user name, the password but nothing happens. I also have a 404 error and the first get I do but I dont believe it has something to do. Its just a response code it throws because it can not find some resources

Comment: Hi. Since the your result tree shows that even the first request "Get Login" fails I would try to troubleshoot your network first (Proxy?).
If your application is available via public internet: try running your test from another internet connection (Wifi at home?) that might involve less corporate infrastructure.
In any case: you should at least get a successful GET request to your landing page - if even that is failing, don't bother to troubleshoot the rest of your script.

Comment: The GET fails but not entirely like POST. Thats because in some of the sub request it makes, fail because they ask for a resource the app is not using or finding.  My main problem is still the 403 problem I have whenever I do a post..... I cannot use this app from another internet connection. I am only able to use it from the network I am right now.